# Table of Datatable not showing up

Tags: datatable, datatables

I created a table

```
<!--Begin::Datatable-->
        <table class="datatable-table" id="kt_datatable">
            <thead class="datatable-head">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Nom</th>
                    <th>Univers</th>
                    <th>Groupe</th>
                    <th>Propriété</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
<!--End::Datatable-->
```

Added a js script to gain some Datatable magics

```
"use strict";
var dataSet = [{
        "groupName": "test",
        "univers": "JARDINAGE",
        "name": "#A DEFINIR",
        "keywords": "test",
        "id": 1,
        "hasBattery": 1,
        "hasBulb": 1,
        "hasMemory": 1,
        "isFurniture": 1,
        "isToxic": 1,
        "isElectronic": 1,
        "obsolete": 0
    },
    {
        "groupName": "#A DEFINIR",
        "univers": "#A DEFINIR",
        "name": "PERCEUSE VISSEUSE",
        "keywords": null,
        "id": 2,
        "hasBattery": 0,
        "hasBulb": 0,
        "hasMemory": 0,
        "isFurniture": 0,
        "isToxic": 0,
        "isElectronic": 0,
        "obsolete": 0
    }
    ];


    var DatatablesBasic = function () {
        var initTableCat = function () {
            var table = $('#kt_datatable');
            table.DataTable({
                responsible: true,
               
                data: dataSet,
                "columnDefs":
                    [{
                        "targets": [0],
                        "visible": false,
                        "searchable": false
                    },
                    {
                        "targets": [1],
                        "searchable": true,
                    },
                    {
                        "targets": [2],
                        "searchable": true,
                    },
                    {
                        "targets": [3],
                        "false": true,
                    },
                    {
                        "targets": [4],
                        "searchable": false,
                        "visible": true,
                    }],
                "columns": [{
                    "data": "id",
                    "name": "id",
                    "autoWidth": true
                },
                {
                    "data": "univers",
                    "name": "univers",
                    "autoWidth": true
                },
                {
                    "data": "groupName",
                    "name": "groupName",
                    "autoWidth": true
                },
                {
                    "data": "name",
                    "name": "name"
                },
                {
                    "data": function (data) {
                        var has_battery = data.hasBattery;
                        var is_electronic = data.isElectronic;
                        var is_toxic = data.isToxic;
                        var has_memory = data.hasMemory;
                        var is_furniture = data.isFurniture;
                        var has_bulb = data.hasBulb;
                        var finalProprety = 0;
                        if (is_electronic) {
                            finalProprety += 1;
                        }
                        if (has_battery) {
                            finalProprety += 1;

                        }
                        if (is_toxic) {
                            finalProprety += finalProprety += 1;
                        }
                        if (has_memory) {
                            finalProprety +=finalProprety += 1;
                        }
                        if (is_furniture) {
                            finalProprety +=finalProprety += 1;

                        }
                        if (has_bulb) {
                            finalProprety +=finalProprety += 1;
                        }
                        return finalProprety;
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "action",
                    "searchable": false,
                    "autoWidth": true,
                    "orderable": false,
                    "defaultContent": '\
                                                                                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon mr-2" title="Edit details">\
                                                                                    <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-md">\
                                                                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1">\
                                                                                            <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">\
                                                                                                <rect x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24"/>\
                                                                                                <path d="M8,17.9148182 L8,5.96685884 C8,5.56391781 8.16211443,5.17792052 8.44982609,4.89581508 L10.965708,2.42895648 C11.5426798,1.86322723 12.4640974,1.85620921 13.0496196,2.41308426 L15.5337377,4.77566479 C15.8314604,5.0588212 16,5.45170806 16,5.86258077 L16,17.9148182 C16,18.7432453 15.3284271,19.4148182 14.5,19.4148182 L9.5,19.4148182 C8.67157288,19.4148182 8,18.7432453 8,17.9148182 Z" fill="#000000" fill-rule="nonzero"\ transform="translate(12.000000, 10.707409) rotate(-135.000000) translate(-12.000000, -10.707409) "/>\
                                                                                                <rect fill="#000000" opacity="0.3" x="5" y="20" width="15" height="2" rx="1"/>\
                                                                                            </g>\
                                                                                        </svg>\
                                                                                    </span>\
                                                                                </a>\
                                                                                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon" title="Delete">\
                                                                                    <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-md">\
                                                                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1">\
                                                                                            <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">\
                                                                                                <rect x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24"/>\
                                                                                                <path d="M6,8 L6,20.5 C6,21.3284271 6.67157288,22 7.5,22 L16.5,22 C17.3284271,22 18,21.3284271 18,20.5 L18,8 L6,8 Z" fill="#000000" fill-rule="nonzero"/>\
                                                                                                <path d="M14,4.5 L14,4 C14,3.44771525 13.5522847,3 13,3 L11,3 C10.4477153,3 10,3.44771525 10,4 L10,4.5 L5.5,4.5 C5.22385763,4.5 5,4.72385763 5,5 L5,5.5 C5,5.77614237 5.22385763,6 5.5,6 L18.5,6 C18.7761424,6 19,5.77614237 19,5.5 L19,5 C19,4.72385763 18.7761424,4.5 18.5,4.5 L14,4.5 Z" fill="#000000" opacity="0.3"/>\
                                                                                            </g>\
                                                                                        </svg>\
                                                                                    </span>\
                                                                                </a>\
                                                                            '
                },
                ]
            });
        };
        return {
            init: function () {
                initTableCat();
            }
        };
    }();
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        DatatablesBasic.init();
    });
```

I'm getting
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wer5w.png) so I'm not sure what to do now. There's no error detected in the console. No pop up message by Datatable telling me there's something wrong. I tried the Datatable Debugger, no issues were detected

Data source:    Javascript
Processing mode:    Client-side
Draws:  1
Columns:    6
Rows - total:   2
Rows - after search:    2
Display start:  0
Display length: 10

I created a fiddle with all the code and it works
https://jsfiddle.net/q6L7g4ro/1/
just not in my application. I don't understand why

Comment: Why is the code in your question (not working!) so different from the code in your Fiddle (working correctly)?

Comment: (Also, there is no such option as `responsible` - did you mean `responsive`?)

Comment: The only difference is finalProprety is returning a number instead of a span. I removed the span with the icons because it was making it the whole thing super long. Yes, I meant responsive

Comment: What about all the _structural_ differences such as this: `var DatatablesBasic = function () { var initTableCat = function () { var table = $('#kt_datatable'); table.DataTable({ ... }; } }`. This structure is part of the code in your question - but the Fiddle is much simpler, and does not contain any of these nested functions.

Comment: I just copy and pasted the code that was in the question to the fiddle, so you can see that it doesn't change anything. The fiddle was different simply because as I'm waiting to find a solution, I'm experimenting things

Comment: I removed some CSS from my code and I could see the table, how it was supposed to be. However that CSS is the whole styling of every pages. I didn't make it myself

Comment: OK - that is progress, thank you! The CSS you are referring to: Is it included in the Fiddle? If not, can you add it, to force the problem to happen? (And tell us what the CSS is). Basically, your Fiddle needs to be a [mre].

Comment: Yes sorry, I removed the script.bundle.css which is found in the fiddle, I wouldn't get a nice layout as I guess it's where comes from most of the styling but I would get the table like shown in the Fiddle. I started to comments part of the code of that css using inspect -> sources -> style.bunde.css. I would mainly comment out wherever I could find datatable. I finaly commented out 3 lines `
```
/*
.datatable:not(.table) {
  display: none; }
*/
```
and it appeared to show me the lines and header I couldn't see before. Only thing is that the layout is now a bit wonky

Comment: You are probably close to a solution. The style `.datatable:not(.table) { display: none; }` will hide all elements which contain the `datatable` class - as long as they do not also contain the `table` class. But your Fiddle does not use either of these classes. It only uses `class="datatable-table"`. Does your _actual_ code also use this? Your Fiddle needs to show the same problem as your actual code. If it does not, then you need to update your Fiddle.

Comment: It's the exact same thing. Interestingly, I used the inspect element to see the code in my class and I saw ``` class="datatable-table dataTable no-footer dtr-inline"```. I didn't write all of those in my code but they are there. once I remove the ````datatable``` in class everything shows up. I found out simply adding ```class="table"``` made it show the data. Only issue now is that the header and the data isn't well lined with each other